# Is it correct and natural to say "wish for someone to do something"?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *wish for someone to do something* in the sense of wanting the person to be able to achieve something? For example:

> I wish for you to finish your work very soon.

If it's not correct or natural, what would you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather odd, so not natural.  Better to just use want

> I want you to finish work very soon.

or more tentatively:

> I hope you'll finish work very soon.

You can use wish as a noun, but for something bigger

> My wish is that you will always love me.

or with the conditional "would" or "wouldn't" to express frustration

> I wish you wouldn't eat with your mouth open.

Comment: As Tim shows, its not the negative but the conditional that shows frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's ok, though I'd try to phrase it slightly more positively, as without more context, it could be taken as rude (like "I wish you would finish your work already, geez!").

It's always good to genuinely wish someone good luck: "I wish you luck in finishing your work quickly." That always has a supportive and positive connotation, and will convey that you are supporting/encouraging the person in their own goal.

Though "Good luck finishing your work anytime soon" would be very sarcastic and perhaps discouraging, the opposite of your intent. But that's an instance of a phrase that can be its own opposite depending on the tone and context: Good luck!

But "I wish you [good] luck" will not sound sarcastic.